# Issue saving files with names containing French accents

Tags: c#, linux, docker, .net-core

I'm writing a c# dotnet core application that will run inside a Linux docker container. The application saves files to the file system with names containing French accents and these files will later be downloaded by users, but the files are being saved with incorrect characters. This is the code that I'm  using:

```
File.WriteAllText($"/src/sociétés.txt", "my text here");
```

When I inspected the docker container, I found that the file was saved as : `soci├®t├®s.txt`

I will need to be able to read the files using their original file names.

Comment: How did you found file name is incorrect? Maybe linux displays it incorrectly?

Comment: It could be that your docker container does not support utf-8 encoding. Or it needs the BOM which is not provided on this function overload [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8). But you could try using the `WriteAllText(path, content, encoding)` overload

Comment: .Net uses UTF-16. You problem likely lies outside your .Net program. Also see [Character Encoding in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to set the french character set to the host:

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y locales locales-all
$ export LC_ALL fr_FR.UTF-8
$ export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
$ export LANGUAGE=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Good luck